# SimpleXML PHP parse OCR XML document

Tags: php, simplexml

Let's say I have this XML document, (actually an XML file containing the result of an OCR document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" version="1.0" producer="ABBYY FineReader Engine 11" languages="">
<page width="317" height="387" resolution="96" originalCoords="1">
<block blockType="Text" l="132" t="18" r="302" b="98"><region><rect l="132" t="18" r="302" b="71"/><rect l="195" t="71" r="302" b="98"/></region>
<text>
<par align="Right">
<line baseline="36" l="179" t="20" r="299" b="36"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
<charParams l="179" t="20" r="199" b="36">W</charParams>
<charParams l="201" t="20" r="210" b="36">h</charParams>
<charParams l="212" t="24" r="223" b="36">a</charParams>
<charParams l="223" t="21" r="229" b="36">t</charParams>
<charParams l="230" t="20" r="236" b="36"> </charParams>
<charParams l="237" t="20" r="253" b="36">M</charParams>
<charParams l="255" t="24" r="266" b="36">a</charParams>
<charParams l="267" t="20" r="277" b="36">k</charParams>
<charParams l="278" t="24" r="288" b="36">e</charParams>
<charParams l="289" t="24" r="299" b="36">s</charParams></formatting></line></par>
<par align="Justified">
<line baseline="68" l="134" t="42" r="299" b="69"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
<charParams l="134" t="42" r="160" b="68">Y</charParams>
<charParams l="155" t="48" r="175" b="69">o</charParams>
<charParams l="177" t="49" r="197" b="69">u</charParams>
<charParams l="200" t="48" r="213" b="68">r</charParams>
<charParams l="214" t="42" r="221" b="68"> </charParams>
<charParams l="222" t="42" r="246" b="68">V</charParams>
<charParams l="244" t="48" r="264" b="69">o</charParams>
<charParams l="264" t="43" r="278" b="68">t</charParams>
<charParams l="278" t="48" r="299" b="69">e</charParams></formatting></line></par>
<par>
<line baseline="95" l="197" t="76" r="299" b="96"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
<charParams l="197" t="76" r="218" b="95">M</charParams>
<charParams l="220" t="81" r="234" b="96">a</charParams>
<charParams l="235" t="77" r="245" b="96">t</charParams>
<charParams l="245" t="77" r="256" b="96">t</charParams>
<charParams l="257" t="81" r="272" b="96">e</charParams>
<charParams l="274" t="81" r="284" b="95">r</charParams>
<charParams l="285" t="76" r="299" b="95">?</charParams></formatting></line></par>
</text>
</block>
<block blockType="Text" l="25" t="83" r="155" b="281"><region><rect l="25" t="83" r="155" b="281"/></region>
<text>
<par align="Justified">
<line baseline="276" l="26" t="82" r="154" b="278"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
<charParams l="26" t="82" r="154" b="278">9</charParams></formatting></line></par>
</text>
</block>
<block blockType="Text" l="73" t="288" r="107" b="322"><region><rect l="73" t="288" r="107" b="322"/></region>
<text>
<par lineSpacing="-1"></par>
</text>
</block>
<block blockType="Text" l="25" t="327" r="136" b="356"><region><rect l="25" t="327" r="136" b="356"/></region>
<text>
<par lineSpacing="1050">
<line baseline="337" l="27" t="328" r="109" b="337"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
<charParams l="27" t="328" r="32" b="337">F</charParams>
<charParams l="33" t="328" r="35" b="337">i</charParams>
<charParams l="36" t="330" r="42" b="337">n</charParams>
<charParams l="42" t="329" r="49" b="337">d</charParams>
<charParams l="50" t="329" r="52" b="337"> </charParams>
<charParams l="53" t="330" r="59" b="337">o</charParams>
<charParams l="60" t="331" r="66" b="337">u</charParams>
<charParams l="66" t="329" r="69" b="337">t</charParams>
<charParams l="70" t="329" r="73" b="337"> </charParams>
<charParams l="74" t="329" r="79" b="337">h</charParams>
<charParams l="80" t="331" r="86" b="337">o</charParams>
<charParams l="87" t="331" r="95" b="337">w</charParams>
<charParams l="96" t="330" r="98" b="337"> </charParams>
<charParams l="99" t="330" r="105" b="337">a</charParams>
<charParams l="106" t="329" r="109" b="337">t</charParams></formatting></line>
<line baseline="351" l="31" t="341" r="133" b="353"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
<charParams l="31" t="343" r="42" b="351" suspicious="1">m</charParams>
<charParams l="44" t="343" r="50" b="351">a</charParams>
<charParams l="51" t="341" r="56" b="351">t</charParams>
<charParams l="57" t="341" r="64" b="351">h</charParams>
<charParams l="66" t="343" r="72" b="351">a</charParams>
<charParams l="74" t="344" r="84" b="351">w</charParams>
<charParams l="85" t="343" r="92" b="351">a</charParams>
<charParams l="94" t="344" r="98" b="351">r</charParams>
<charParams l="99" t="343" r="106" b="351">e</charParams>
<charParams l="107" t="348" r="110" b="351">.</charParams>
<charParams l="111" t="343" r="119" b="351">o</charParams>
<charParams l="120" t="344" r="125" b="351">r</charParams>
<charParams l="125" t="343" r="133" b="353">g</charParams></formatting></line></par>
</text>
</block>
<block blockType="Text" l="6" t="364" r="312" b="376"><region><rect l="6" t="364" r="312" b="376"/></region>
<text>
<par align="Justified">
<line baseline="372" l="7" t="365" r="309" b="374"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
<charParams l="7" t="365" r="14" b="372">M</charParams>
<charParams l="15" t="367" r="19" b="372">a</charParams>
<charParams l="19" t="366" r="22" b="372">t</charParams>
<charParams l="23" t="366" r="27" b="372">h</charParams>
<charParams l="27" t="367" r="33" b="372">e</charParams>
<charParams l="33" t="367" r="40" b="372">m</charParams>
<charParams l="40" t="367" r="45" b="372">a</charParams>
<charParams l="45" t="366" r="48" b="372">t</charParams>
<charParams l="48" t="365" r="50" b="372">i</charParams>
<charParams l="50" t="367" r="55" b="372">c</charParams>
<charParams l="55" t="367" r="60" b="372">s</charParams>
<charParams l="61" t="365" r="62" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="62" t="365" r="68" b="372">A</charParams>
<charParams l="68" t="367" r="75" b="372">w</charParams>
<charParams l="75" t="367" r="80" b="372">a</charParams>
<charParams l="80" t="367" r="83" b="372">r</charParams>
<charParams l="83" t="367" r="88" b="372">e</charParams>
<charParams l="88" t="367" r="93" b="372">n</charParams>
<charParams l="93" t="367" r="98" b="372">e</charParams>
<charParams l="98" t="367" r="103" b="372">s</charParams>
<charParams l="103" t="367" r="107" b="372">s</charParams>
<charParams l="108" t="365" r="109" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="110" t="365" r="117" b="372">M</charParams>
<charParams l="118" t="367" r="123" b="372">o</charParams>
<charParams l="123" t="367" r="127" b="372">n</charParams>
<charParams l="128" t="366" r="131" b="372">t</charParams>
<charParams l="131" t="365" r="136" b="372">h</charParams>
<charParams l="137" t="365" r="138" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="139" t="367" r="143" b="370">â€¢</charParams>
<charParams l="144" t="365" r="145" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="146" t="365" r="152" b="372">A</charParams>
<charParams l="151" t="367" r="157" b="374">p</charParams>
<charParams l="157" t="367" r="162" b="372">n</charParams>
<charParams l="162" t="366" r="164" b="372" suspicious="1">l</charParams>
<charParams l="165" t="365" r="166" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="167" t="365" r="171" b="372">2</charParams>
<charParams l="172" t="365" r="177" b="372">0</charParams>
<charParams l="177" t="365" r="182" b="372">0</charParams>
<charParams l="182" t="365" r="187" b="372">8</charParams>
<charParams l="188" t="365" r="190" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="191" t="367" r="194" b="370">â€¢</charParams>
<charParams l="195" t="365" r="197" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="198" t="365" r="206" b="372">M</charParams>
<charParams l="206" t="367" r="211" b="372">a</charParams>
<charParams l="212" t="366" r="215" b="372">t</charParams>
<charParams l="216" t="365" r="220" b="372">h</charParams>
<charParams l="221" t="367" r="226" b="372" suspicious="1">e</charParams>
<charParams l="227" t="367" r="235" b="372">m</charParams>
<charParams l="235" t="367" r="240" b="372">a</charParams>
<charParams l="241" t="366" r="244" b="372">t</charParams>
<charParams l="245" t="365" r="246" b="372">i</charParams>
<charParams l="247" t="367" r="252" b="372">c</charParams>
<charParams l="253" t="367" r="257" b="372">s</charParams>
<charParams l="258" t="367" r="260" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="261" t="367" r="265" b="372">a</charParams>
<charParams l="266" t="367" r="271" b="372">n</charParams>
<charParams l="272" t="365" r="277" b="372">d</charParams>
<charParams l="278" t="365" r="279" b="372"> </charParams>
<charParams l="280" t="365" r="286" b="372">V</charParams>
<charParams l="286" t="367" r="291" b="372">o</charParams>
<charParams l="291" t="366" r="295" b="372">t</charParams>
<charParams l="295" t="365" r="297" b="372">i</charParams>
<charParams l="298" t="367" r="303" b="372">n</charParams>
<charParams l="304" t="367" r="309" b="374">g</charParams></formatting></line></par>
</text>
</block>
<block blockType="Separator" l="0" t="379" r="310" b="387"><region><rect l="0" t="379" r="310" b="387"/></region>
<separator type="Black" thickness="8"><start x="0" y="383"/><end x="310" y="383"/>
</separator>
</block>
<block blockType="Picture" l="1" t="362" r="316" b="376"><region><rect l="1" t="362" r="316" b="376"/></region>
</block>
</page>
</document>
```

How would I go about getting the contents of each `charParams` in the XML document using `simplexml_load_string`? I would like to `echo` the contents of each `charParms` inside each `line`. And after each `line`, it would `echo` a `<br>`. Thanks! Oh, and would this be accomplished with `foreach`? Please point me to the direction.

Like in this case, I would like it to output something beggining like:

```
What Makes<br>Your Vote<br>Matter?<br>Find out how at
```

ect.

Just to give you the basic idea.

Comment: Can you show some example expected output for the above XML? Do you just want `What Makes Your ...` as a string?

Comment: @cbuckley yes, basically. Edited my post to clarify.

Comment: @cbuckley thanks for your interest/help BTW. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the blocks/paragraphs/lines/characters like so:

```
$string = '';
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file');

foreach ($xml->page->block as $block) {
    if ($block->text->count()) {
        foreach ($block->text->par as $par) {
            if ($par->line->count()) {
                foreach ($par->line as $line) {
                    foreach ($line->formatting->charParams as $char) {
                        $string .= $char;
                    }

                    $string .= "\n";
                }
            }

            $string .= "\n";
        }
    }

    $string .= "\n";
}
```

**EDIT**: I added a little more error checking to avoid the loop warning. Currently everything is joined with new lines, so you might want to change those to alter your output.

[Here's a working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/b9tlBF).

Comment: Ah doesn't work. :( These are the erros I get: Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <document xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScha-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml http://www.abbyy.comhtml/dumbocr/post.php on line 108
and 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/76/7290476/html/dumbocr/post.php on line 110

Comment: Thanks for your help, BTW. Look at these errors: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/76/7290476/html/dumbocr/post.php on line 110  and   Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <document xmlns="abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLScha-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml abbyy.comhtml/dumbocr/post.php on line 108

Comment: When parsing XML, you should always consider namespaces; even if your 1 sample document does not have it. If the elements would have a prefix, the document would be syntactically the same, but your parser would break.

Comment: @Evert I don't think that's really relevant here, as it's fairly unusual for a source of files to switch from producing them with no namespace, or an un-prefixed default namespace, to prefixes which have to be dealt with.

Comment: @SolèneLeVan It looks like you're using `simplexml_load_file` when you mean `simplexml_load_string` - one expects the name of a file to load, the other expects a string which is the contents of an XML document.

Comment: @SolèneLeVan there also looks to be some [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in the string; you may want to watch out for future character encoding problems.

Comment: @IMSoP yes I noticed that, but when I change it to simplexml_load_string, it still doesn't work. I had changed it to simplexml_load_string before I had even posted the errors here.

Comment: @SolèneLeVan So what errors do you get with `simplexml_load_string`?

Comment: @cbuckley Yeah, there is some character encoding issues in what I have. :( But I don't know how to fix that! :( I don't want some random weird characters appearing in my string...

Comment: @SolèneLeVan I've edited the answer to fix the error and added an example. There are plenty of character encoding questions on here, so it's worth searching for.

Comment: @cbuckley Thanks! One more thing though: why does it output `string(152)` when I run it? It works well, but at the beginning of the outputted content (in the demo you provided), it displayed text: `string(152)` Thanks! If this gets fixed, I will accept your answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: @SolèneLeVan that's what happens with the output from [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) — you should check it out some time, it's invaluable for debugging!

Comment: @IMSoP: it's just a best practice. I certainly have changed the prefix over the years as requirements and systems evolve. The best practice is to be prefix-agnostic. XPath deals nicely with this.

Comment: @Evert What, exactly, is a best practice? You mention the (potential) problem, but not your solution. I certainly agree that not relying on prefixes remaining constant is not best practice, but allowing for the default namespace to change (without any structural changes which would require maintenance anyway) seems pretty extreme.

Comment: @IMSoP: Sorry, I forgot to mention that a change from 'not having a prefix' to 'having a prefix' still makes the XML document syntactically identical. _If_ there's a namespace identifier, the best practice is make sure your parser works regardless of the prefix, or if there's any at all.

Comment: @IMSoP: If a different OCR system (or version of the software) spits out a document that does employ a prefix, it will still adhere to the same schema, but your parser will break. If your argument is simply that this 'typically does not happen', well then I can accept your point, but I do disagree :)