# Preserve linebreak txt php

Tags: php, echo

How can I read a `.txt` file from my server, and preserve it's linebreaks?
Note that the linebreaks aren't like this `/n` or something, they are more like

this. You know, just a new line in plain text.

I would like to echo the `.txt` file from my server, this is in PHP or something, while preserving the linebreaks.

Thanks a heck in advance ! :)

Comment: The line break is preserved, but the HTML client is not showing them. Use "View Source" in your browser and they should be there.
In your HTML you could use <pre> ... </pre> tags around the .txt echo

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: You should know that lines which are "like this" are really like `\n`, that's just how you represent them. Similarly tab character are not like `    (4 spaces supposed to be there :P)`  but like `\t`, etc. It's just a way to represent them in your code.

Comment: Do note that this question is a backup plan: an alternative to something I wanted to do. I'd prefer, though, if I found a solution to this, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268731/simplexml-php-parse-charparms#comment19807619_14268731

Comment: @jadkik94 wow very interesting! then why doesn't it display `\n` in the browser?

Comment: @SolèneLeVan Because once you `echo` it, PHP knows that `\\`something means it's something special. When it sees `\n` it goes to the next line, when it sees `\t` it adds 4 "white spaces", when it sees `\\\\` it will add `\\` literally. These are the ones you will encounter mostly, it's called escaping a character. (You see even stackoverflow says it's something special and breaks my formatting!

Comment: @jadkik94 wow yur genious! you get my uupvote!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For output? Just use `nl2br`

```
$file = file_get_contents( 'file.txt' );
echo nl2br( $file );
```

Also works with `fopen`.

Comment: WOW this worked... jadkik94 was right! `You should know that lines which are "like this" are really like \n, that's just how you represent them. Similarly tab character are not like ` (4 spaces supposed to be there :P)` but like \t, etc. It's just a way to represent them in your code.`

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer all over the place, the op says NOTHING about HTML in the .txt file. And even says "You know, just a new line in plain text.", so why on this answer and all over the place do people claim nl2br() to be the fix, when that clearly just converts new lines \n to <br /> without the need of you doing it with str_replace.. My situation involves a working template of text with line breaks when on a linux environment, but when the same code is put on wamp, my file_get_contents REMOVES THE NEW LINES in ANY HTML FILE, being that the specific data is in a TEXTAREA in HTML.

Comment: @NinjaKC If you have a new question, please use the Ask Question link in the upper right hand corner of the page.

Comment: maybe my comment wasn't clear enough.. no extra question is needed.. the op speaks of txt, not html, the answer gives an html solution by assumptions made, and this all in turns screws over seo for someone who is looking for a solution to the ACTUAL question asked.. Which defeats the purpose of this website.. For anyone in the future, note that Apache on some setups Removes New Lines From TEXT, I will produce an answer here to the ACTUAL question if I can find the reason behind it. I'm surprised you, being a more active user, doesn't see a problem with your answer given.

Answer (score 2):

The line breaks *are* preserved without you needing to do anything. You can easily verify this by running the code from the command line, for example with

```
php -r "readfile('text.txt');"
```

However, in HTML whitespace is [collapsed](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html) by default. If you want to preserve it use the CSS [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop) attribute like this:

```
<div style="white-space: pre"><?php readfile('text.txt'); ?></div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks! :) You get my upvote... +1 but njk's the best because it replaces the new lines with `br`.

Comment: @SolèneLeVan: I 'm fine with the other answer being accepted, but why is replacing newlines with `<br>` better? Or even desirable? You should think about that.

Comment: Your right, my post said perserver linebreaks, not create br, but I kinda like the fact that PHP creates a linebreak before it even sends it to the server... :( I'm torn! Whose do I select as answer?

Comment: @SolèneLeVan: Which answer you select doesn't matter, leave it as is. What matters is what you choose to do when you write code. :)

Comment: :) I guess... but your answer also perservers whitspace to, and tabs, correct? Because it uses the white-space property?

Comment: @SolèneLeVan: Yes, it preserves *all* whitespace. But you don't need to ask me, try it out!

Comment: This is not the case on my wamp setup, and have seen it before on a clients linux setup. For some reason this same script above, removes new lines from a TXT file when output to the browser. Like its a php setting or something.